# Create scalable flex children

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I have a container element that can have a variable amount of child elements and I want to scale the width of those child elements.

I've set up a simple plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ef0AGPsK7FJJyBqgWuMi?p=preview

In this plunker you can shrink the DOM and the `name` and `number` elements will use their ellipsis to fit the content in the parent. This is fine.

But when you enlarge the DOM you see that the child elements are spread out so they are equally divided over the parent. this is because of the `flex: 1`. But I would like the container elements to be the the max width of what they would need to show the content correctly instead of filling up the parent container element.

```css
/* Styles go here */

.conversation-container {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.conversation-container .conversation-holder {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.conversation-container .conversation-holder .name {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.conversation-container .conversation-holder .number {
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 50%;

}

.conversation-container1 {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.conversation-container1 .conversation-holder {

  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.conversation-container1 .conversation-holder .name {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.conversation-container1 .conversation-holder .number {
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 50%;

}
```

```html
<h1>Scalable content using flex, example 1</h1>
  <div class="conversation-container">
    <div class="conversation-holder">
      <span class="name">Namefrom Someone</span>
      <span class="number">555666444213321</span>
    </div>
    <div class="conversation-holder">
      <span class="name">Namefrom Someone</span>
      <span class="number">555666444123123</span>
    </div>
    <div class="conversation-holder">
      <span class="name">Namefrom Someone</span>
      <span class="number">555666444123321</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <h1>Scalable content using flex, example 2</h1>
  <div class="conversation-container1">
    <div class="conversation-holder">
      <span class="name">Namefrom Someone</span>
      <span class="number">555666444213321</span>
    </div>
    <div class="conversation-holder">
      <span class="name">Namefrom Someone</span>
      <span class="number">555666444123123</span>
    </div>
    <div class="conversation-holder">
      <span class="name">Namefrom Someone</span>
      <span class="number">555666444123321</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `flex: 0 1 auto` (tell it not to *grow* but *shrink* is okay, and set `flex-basis` property to `auto`) to your `conversation-holder` (and maybe `min-width: 0` if you want to *shrink* the `coversation-holder` more).

Now instead of having `width: 50%` on both `name` and `number` and *floating* the `number` element to left, you can use a *row-reverse* flexbox on `conversation-holder`. See demo below:

```css
.conversation-container {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.conversation-container .conversation-holder {
  flex: 0 1 auto; /* CHANGED */
  min-width: 0; /* ADDED */
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-right: 5px;
  /* ADDED BELOW */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.conversation-container .conversation-holder .name {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  /* width: 50%; */
  display: inline-block;
}

.conversation-container .conversation-holder .number {
  /* float: left; */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  /* width: 50%; */
}
```

```html
<div class="conversation-container">
  <div class="conversation-holder">
    <span class="name">Namefrom Someone</span>
    <span class="number">555666444213321</span>
  </div>
  <div class="conversation-holder">
    <span class="name">Namefrom Someone</span>
    <span class="number">555666444123123</span>
  </div>
  <div class="conversation-holder">
    <span class="name">Namefrom Someone</span>
    <span class="number">555666444123321</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was pretty close, couldn't figure out the rest.